# Redefine click selector jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, bind, redefine

I am trying to make jQuery update the values in the selector after they are passed. What I mean is this.

I am passing the selector like this.

```
var items = ['.item-1','.item-2'...];
$(items[1]).click(function(){....});
```

And then in the end of the function I change the order of the items array.

```
var items = ['.item-1','.item-2'...];
$(items[1]).click(function(){
    // ... function
    items = ['.item-3', '.item-1' ...];
});
```

Now the problem is that the function is binded to the inital items[1], so my changing of the array does not really matter. I am pretty sure there should be a not too complicated solution, so can you please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Could you explain the higher level goal? You may be going about this the wrong way, but it's hard to tell what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: @Barmar I am creating a animation between 3 items, where if you click the middle one the animation is triggered and the movement is as follows:
First -> Middle
Middle -> Third
Third -> First

Comment: How about using event delegation and changing the classes of the elements.

Comment: Is it any beneficial ? Because Claudio's solution works perfect.

Comment: It's more idiomatic. You can write the event handler once, it doesn't need to redefine itself each time.

Comment: Fair enough, I will look into it. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method in combination with a recursion schema

```
var items = ['.item-1','.item-2','.item-3'];
$(items[1]).one('click', clickHandler);

function clickHandler() {
    items = //re-sort items;
    $(items[1]).one('click', clickHandler);
}
```

Take into account that arrays index is zero based so you're using the second item and not the first when doing `items[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use a recursive method.

It could be:

```
   var items = ['.item-1','.item-2'];
    function redefine(){
        $(items[1]).click(function(){
            items = ['.item-3', '.item-1'];
            $(this).unbind("click");
            redefine();
        });
    }
    redefine()
```

Comment: That is perfect, but Claudio's way of presenting it seems a bit clearer. Thank you !